# Exception Handling in ASP.NET MVC 4, 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4

I want to trace or handle Exception globally.

> **1.Which is handled by user code?**
>   **2.Which is not handled by user code?**

both the type

how is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/handling-errors-in-asp.net-mvc-applications.htm

Shows different ways of handling errors globally.  Setting a global exception handling filter is the usual.

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new SpecialHandleErrorAttributeCreatedByYou());
```

You would derive a new Attribute from HandleErrorAttribute and put your logic in there, overriding the OnException method.

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
```

However this will not show you exceptions that are handled by other code.  That is the point, they are handled so they do not continue to bubble up the stack.  You would have to put code in each of those catch blocks to either do what you want.

Comment: it mean no chance to trace those exception which all handled by user code ?

Comment: No chance outside of something very advanced, like plugging in to the AppDomain and handling the exception before an user code handles it, like the VS debugger is capable of.  You might be able to do something like that with Fody IL Weaving (weaving in handlers wherever you see a catch block).  https://github.com/Fody/Fody

Answer (score 2):

Global error handling:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
        }
}
```

Or override OnException method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Exception ex = filterContext.Exception;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, "Controller","Action");

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = "Error",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: will it work with those exception which all handled by user code ?

Comment: If you handle an exception and you'll not re-thrown it once again it cannot handle it again. Exception handled once can't be handled second time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can override. [HandleErrorAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)
And register it globally

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
filters.Add(YourNewHandler());
...
}
```

Comment: will it work with those exception which all handled by user code ?